# Learning NAnt - what does [+|-] in the help mean?

Tags: nant

If I type `nant -help` I receive help information about the various command-line options.

Some, such as `find` have a suffix of `[+|-]`, e.g.

```
-find[+|-]                     Search parent directories for build file
```

What does the `[+|-]` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command line options syntax, sometimes `[...]` is used to denote optional items, and `|` is used to denote alternate. So it looks like there are 3 different variations here:

```
-find
-find+
-find-
```

The documentation should clarify what each of these variation means.

#### See also

- [Forum post](http://www.jaggersoft.com/Wikka/wikka.php?wakka=February2006)

  > ... `-find+` looks for `nant.build` traversing *back up* the folder structure

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](http://nant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nant/nant/src/NAnt.Core/Util/CommandLineParser.cs?revision=1.15&view=markup), find is a boolean type, and adding + or - simply sets it to true or false accordingly. I suppose the - is useful to override a previous setting, don't know why you'd want to have an explicit + though.